# How to set the date-time in the form for twitter-bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, html, date, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the twitter bootstrap and I need to set the input as date-time for one of the labels in the form and I am not sure how to do it..

I am following this:

https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker and i am trying to do the one with the options

I tried this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=""{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/datepicker.css">
 <script src = "{{STATIC_URL}}js/Datepicker.js></script>
 <script>
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
  });
 </script>
 <label>Created:</label>
 <input type="text" value="02-16-2012" id="datepicker" rel="datapicker" />
 <br/><br/>
```

Besides, i would take the label to show the current date instead of the value that i type i initially.

Need some help on it. Would really appreciate any help..

But it is not working... Not sure what the error was...

Edited Version:

```
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=""{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/datepicker.css">
  <script>
   $('#datepicker').datepicker({
      format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
    });
  </script>
  <script src = "{{STATIC_URL}}js/Datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <label>Created:</label>
    <input type="text" value ="06/11/2012"id="datepicker"/>
    <br/><br/>
```

Comment: Can you put you're code in a jsFiddle.

Comment: Are data-date and data-date-format meant to be on the parent div of the input?

Comment: i have been referring to this: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: You need jquery to make it works.

Comment: so what i should do to set the jquery?

Comment: do i need to download jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
});
```

is jquery so add

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to your code.

It works for me http://jsfiddle.net/baptme/9r2E4/

Replace

```
<input type="text" value ="06/11/2012"id="datepicker"/>
```

With

```
<input type="text" value="06-11-2012" id="datepicker"/>
```

Comment: where do i add the jquery statement? under the script tag?

Comment: First remove the space in "< script" line2 and add before <script ... Datepicker.js>...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lakshmen/W5z9 have a look at this.. what is the error... i followed yours...

Comment: You've missed the last character of the url : jsfiddle.net/lakshmen/W5z9?

Comment: You're not putting any effort into it and SO is not a chat.

Comment: I allready gave you the answer. the problem come from value ="06/11/2012" and datepicker({format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'});. You must have the same format on both a remove the between value and =.