# Html Bootstrap preload datetime input field not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to pre-load a datetime input so that the user has a default value. In this example I´m using the current Date/Time as default. I´m using Bootstrap 3. Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="startDateTime">Start Date and Time</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="startDateTime">
    </div>
    <script>
          document.getElementById("startDateTime").value = new Date();
          alert('Loaded');
    </script>
</div>
```

I have tried different variations but the datetime picker does not pre load, opening always with empty data (dd/mm/aaaa --:--) ? Check it here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cox123456a/5scCg/1/).

Can someone help me to solve that ? Thanks in advance...

Comment: I don't see a picker in your fiddle code

Comment: Matt, Sorry? Didn´t get the point..

Comment: Got it. Fixed. Try the link again.

Comment: been trying to google to see if I can help.  found links like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975443/how-to-set-the-date-time-in-the-form-for-twitter-bootstrap but they all set the default in the date picker call which I don't see in your code.  Sorry I can't be more help